# Talend DI changing Excel cells colour

Tags: excel, jobs, talend, data-integration

is there a way in Talend Open Studio for Data Integration (v. 6.3) to set the background colour of cells in a generated Excel file? 
I looked for some information regarding this but I haven't been able to find a good answer (apart from some people saying it simply can't be done - but as a passionate programmer I refuse to believe that ;) )

I am using tFileExcelSheetOutput....

Answer (score 1):

The base `Talend` product offers very limited `Excel` functionality, particularly with regards to formatting.  There is no `Open XML` interface or `OLE Automation` with `Excel` built into `Talend`.  But it is possible of course.  You will need to build or use a custom component.

- To build your own this [article](https://help.talend.com/display/KB/How+to+create+a+custom+component) will get you started
- Its possible someone else created a component and is willing to share it with you.  Check out Talend [Exchange](https://exchange.talend.com/).

Comment: jlolling created some talend components that can do this for sure.